# Can't debug ASP.NET Core Webapp 6.0 in VSCode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

Earlier, I created my ASP.NET Core web app using the 6.0 *preview* build, and I was able to debug it in VSCode.

Then, I upgraded my app to the final 6.0 release a week ago. Since then I could no longer debug it. The debugger starts and stops immediately within 1 second.

I'm on Mac OS, using the release build of dotnet core 6.0.

Here's my `launch.config` entry for debugging:

```
{
  "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "Build:Api",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/api/bin/Debug/net6.0/api.dll",
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
  },
  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

I have checked and all my extensions are up-to-date.

Is there a way I can at least see the log to figure out why the debugger fails to start?

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.  Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you may need to install the appropriate .net 6.0 sdk

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Ray H.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have already installed it, but it still doesn't work.